# .NET 4.0 System.Timers.Timer seems to not execute the elapsed event after some time

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that needs to run 24x7. It uses a Timers.Timer to execute an elapsed event in a calculated interval. After some time, 3-5 days, the timer just stops executing the elapsed event. This does not happen in all of the users, some 4 or 5 reports this.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public static MyClass thisMyClass;

    private Timer myTimer;
    PERIOD = 60000;
    private SomeHighResolutionClass _lapseTimer;

    private double _timeToNextExec
    {
        get
        {
            double lapseTime = _lapseTimer.LapseTime();
            double next = PERIOD - lapseTime;

            if (next > 0)
            {
                return next;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
        myTimer = new Timer(PERIOD);
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        // Only raise the event the first time Interval elapses.
        myTimer.AutoReset = false;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void myTimer_Elapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogHere("Elapse started"); // Entry log
        try
        {
            try
            {
                _lapseTimer.Start();
                DoStuffHere();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            myTimer.Interval = _timeToNextExec;
            LogHere("restarting timer interval " + myTimer.Interval); // Finally Log
            myTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void DoStuffHere()
    {
        //some processing that could take 1-2 or more seconds to process
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        thisMyClass = new MyClass();    
    }

    public static IMyClass Interface
    {
        get { return thisMyClass as IMyClass; }
    }
}
```

On another class, this is initialized statically.

```
MyClass.Initialize()
```

The timer interval is variable. and it is based on the elapsed time of the `DoStuffHere();`. If it takes longer than PERIOD, then it would still be executed as long as DoStuffHere finishes.

Based on the data that we are receiving, the elapsed event is completed and both Entry log and Finally log are logged successfully. 
We are also sure that the Timer is restarted/enabled based on the memory dump that we received and based on the information from the memory dump, the timer is enabled and should trigger elapsed even but did not. The memory dump was obtained when we already observed that the `DoStuffHere()` is not getting executed. There are no also no exception as logged in `LogExceptions();`.

**Timer Info From Memory Dump**

```
70dcf7dc  40001e0        4        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 __identity
703d7618  40002c3        8 ...ponentModel.ISite  0 instance 00000000 site
703d6b74  40002c4        c ....EventHandlerList  0 instance 00000000 events
70dcf7dc  40002c2       cc        System.Object  0   static 00000000 EventDisposed
70dca574  4002dbd       10        System.Double  1 instance 55949.118673 interval
70dd6820  4002dbe       2c       System.Boolean  1 instance        1 enabled
70dd6820  4002dbf       2d       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 initializing
70dd6820  4002dc0       2e       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 delayedEnable
703ceb80  4002dc1       18 ...apsedEventHandler  0 instance 0246fc8c onIntervalElapsed
70dd6820  4002dc2       2f       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 autoReset
703d5fcc  4002dc3       1c ...SynchronizeInvoke  0 instance 00000000 synchronizingObject
70dd6820  4002dc4       30       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 disposed
70dcacfc  4002dc5       20 ...m.Threading.Timer  0 instance 0246fcb8 timer
70dcb07c  4002dc6       24 ...ing.TimerCallback  0 instance 0246fc6c callback
70dcf7dc  4002dc7       28        System.Object  0 instance 0246fcac cookie
```

I am really puzzled and clueless. Please help guys.

--**UPDATE - Additional information regarding threads** -- The number of threads seems to go up after the Timer has stopped so this may not be the one causing us the problems.

```
0:000> !threads -live
ThreadCount:      809
UnstartedThread:  790
BackgroundThread: 14
PendingThread:    790
DeadThread:       1
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                   PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
       ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
   0    1   d4c 012be0a0   2006020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 STA
   2    2   d54 012c9dd0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA (Finalizer)
   3    3   d60 0131a0c0   100a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
   4    4   d64 01331ef0      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
   6    6   d70 01337348   1000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
   7    7   d8c 0133f100   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
   9    a   f90 06c2c948   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  10    b   9a8 06c33f48   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  11    c   584 06c34450   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  12    d   5f4 06c35758   200b020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 MTA
  13   12   970 06ca6d08   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  14    e  1254 06ca8b38   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  15   13  12f0 06ca9548   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  16    5  10ec 06ca7210   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  17    f  1d90 06cac290   a009220 Enabled  259e45ac:259e4fe8 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  19   19  1124 06ca7718   8009220 Enabled  258f90c4:258fafe8 012b7310     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  20    8  1394 06ca9040   2000220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 012b7310     0 Ukn
  22  322  21d4 13698f50   2000220 Enabled  259e6394:259e6fe8 012b7310     0 Ukn
```

Cheers! TIA!

Comment: How do you use this class with no possibility to create an instance?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, sorry about that, I updated the codes above to show how this was initialized statically using `MyClass.Initialize()` and to access the static instance, there is an `static IMyClass Interface` object which returns the `static thisMyClass`

Comment: Did you make sure (from the dump) that the interval is set to a correct value? Is your thread-pool fully utilized after a few days maybe? Like 250 threads waiting? Then, a timer tick cannot get through.

Comment: @usr, Yes, the dump says `Interval` is `55949.118673`. Regarding threads, see above for updates. In summary, there were 809 threads, 790 were unstarted, 1 is Dead, etc. Does this mean anything bad?

Answer (score 2):

Your threads have a problem. [An explanation of what the specific counters mean.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2005/08/30/457756.aspx)

There should not be ~800 threads in your application(!). Furthermore they seem to be unable to completely start (for some reason). It could be resource exhaustion (probably memory). Heavy paging.

Find out why there are so many threads. Maybe you are running lots of blocking work on many threads or posting many such work items to the threadpool.

Comment: Now that was really enlightening, I do have the memory dump, but I don't really know where to start the analysis. I felt really 'dumb' when I asked on my comment above "does this mean anything bad?" :P. I had a laugh at myself. Thanks!

Comment: I have never performed dump analysis myself so I don't know about that. I'd start with a code review of all the places you start threads or queue work to the pool.

Comment: I don't think the call stacks in the dump will be of great help as the threads have so far failed to start. Worth a try, though.

Comment: You are right @usr. Oh boy. memory goes up when myTimer gets held up (as you mentioned) because of too many threads. But I wonder why the number of threads shoot up to that number. I usually have 20-30 (or maybe 50 when busy). Let me get back to you on that. Thanks

Comment: Hi @usr, we received a new perf logs from the users regarding the recent Timer failure. The problem seems not to be caused by the number of threads. When the Timer failed to function, the current # of threads from the process is at minimum (22 threads) and the number of un-started threads just eventually goes up after some time after the Timer has failed to function. Any more ideas?

Comment: No more ideas. I don't know under what exact circumstances the CLR fails to start unstarted threads. This is certainly not normal. Check for other types of exhaustion such as handle leaks (check the handle count).

Answer (score 0):

If your system real-time is not very strict, you try to

```
if (next > 10)
        {
            return next;
        }
        else
        {
            return 10;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Lichdr, That could be one.  But, based on the memory dump, the next timer should trigger (`instance 55949.118673 interval`) 55949.118673 milliseconds after, which means that the DoStuffHere() was done roughly 4 seconds. Thanks though.