# c# Custom Threading Leak and WaitHandle.WaitAny()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application that seems to leak. One of of the Timers.Timer object stopped to elapse events and starts to leak threads as in [.NET 4.0 System.Timers.Timer seems to not execute the elapsed event after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521689/net-4-0-system-timers-timer-seems-to-not-execute-the-elapsed-event-after-some-t).

There are other threads and some just stopped to process and shows below stack trace. There are about 8 waiting threads in the `~*e !clrstack`

```
Child SP IP       Call Site
07baf8f8 778f5cd4 [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 07baf8f8] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean, Boolean)
07baf9c0 70d0dd2b System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean)
07baf9e0 018a6129 MyDatabaseThread.threadMain()
07bafa30 018a5eee <Module>.OS.UnmanagedThreadProc(Void*)
```

Below is some of the code snippets under threadMain()

```
WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[2];
waitHandles[0] = _threadAbort;
WaitHandles[1] = _messageWaiting;
WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
```

the wait handles are declared as follows.

```
private AutoResetEvent _messageWaiting;
private ManualResetEvent _threadAbort;
```

Any help would be appreciated. I cannot figure what is causing the hangup. Thanks