# Timers.Timer stopped triggering elapsed event and !Threads showing 1023 unstarted and pending threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

my application has a Timers.Timer implementation as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521689/net-4-0-system-timers-timer-seems-to-not-execute-the-elapsed-event-after-some-t) question which seems to stop triggering its elapsed event after some time (days or weeks) [the elapsed event is supposed to run every 60 seconds see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521689/net-4-0-system-timers-timer-seems-to-not-execute-the-elapsed-event-after-some-t) for details]

```
0:000> !threads -live
ThreadCount:      1041
UnstartedThread:  1023
BackgroundThread: 11
PendingThread:    1023
DeadThread:       3
Hosted Runtime:   no
```

Later, we found out that when the the elapsed event stopped getting fired, the number of `unstarted` and `pending` threads also rise consistently until `1023` limit is reached. Then the process gets stuck.

What is the cause/reason or the relation between my Timer not firing the event and the eventual rise in the # threads (unstarted and pending)?

[image: perf logs showing the rise in thread count when the timer stopped firing the elapsed event]

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly your timer event handler is not exiting. Either it's blocking (in a `Sleep` or waiting on some event), or it's gone into an infinite loop. Then the next timer event comes along and *it* either blocks or goes into an infinite loop. Etc . . .

You can determine if this is the case by changing your timer event handler so that it tells you if it's re-entered:

```
private bool _inTimer = false;
private void TimerTick(object Sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_inTimer)
    {
        // there's already a timer running.
        // log a message or notify you in some other way.
    }
    _inTimer = true;
    // do your processing here
    // and then clear the flag
    _inTimer = false;
}
```

That will tell you if what I suspect is the case. But don't use it as a production way to prevent concurrent timer instances, though. There's a race condition with the `Boolean` flag. If you want to prevent concurrent timer ticks, disable the timer when you enter the method, and then re-enable it when you exit. Like this:

```
private void TimerTick(object Sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _myTimer.Enabled = false;
    // do processing
    // then re-enable the timer
    _myTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

On a related note, the other thing that can cause your timer to appear to stop functioning is that it throws an exception which the runtime library squashes without surfacing. That behavior is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

So if an exception goes uncaught in your event handler, it's dropped on the floor. It's for this reason that I recommend against using `System.Timers.Timer`. I would suggest using S[ystem.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, as it doesn't suffer from this idiotic design.

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel, this answer is really helpful. What you suggest makes sense. Actually if you check my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521689/net-4-0-system-timers-timer-seems-to-not-execute-the-elapsed-event-after-some-t (which shows the implementation of the Timer class) I think what you suggest has already been covered (Enabled = true/false) but the problem is still there. Also, we added a try-catch statement so we do not miss any unhandled errors.

Comment: @junPac: The code you posted in that question uses a one-shot timer to prevent current ticks, which should work. However, it calls `_lapseTimer.Start()`, and I don't know what that is. Is it another timer, or a `Stopwatch`? Could the problem be with the `_lapseTimer`?

Comment: the `_lapsetimer` is simply a timer used to obtain the lapse time to calculate the `_timeToNextExec` to ensure that `DoStuffHere()` would be triggered on a timely manner (60 seconds interval). I do not think it is the source of the problem because the last `DoStuffHere()` was properly executed and completed/finished before the next elapsed event was not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up revising/revamping the Timer implementation and use a Thread with a do-while loop, instead. This will avoid the 'unknown' problems we are getting from the Timers elapsed event not firing up.

Thanks all